# R package not working properly when using PHP exec() function

Tags: php, r, exec, rscript

**UPDATE: SOLVED**
I've discovered the issue.

Using the .libPaths() function, I was able to determine that the default directory that the HH package installed into was **not** included in the library paths when running Rscript through PHP, even though it was appearing when R was executing the same code through the command prompt.

I've resolved the issue by include a separate call to .libPaths('new/file/path'); in my dynamically created syntax.  When I do this, test <-require('HH'); test; returns TRUE;

Thanks to all who helped.

I'm in the process of creating a PHP script that will run some analyses in R.  This analysis requires the hov.bf() function, which is a part of the [HH](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HH/index.html) package, but all R output (and presumably processes associated with R) stops from the line where the hov.bf() function is called. The same symptom occurs if I try loading the HH library via library('HH');. What's confusing me, the exact same R syntax code executes and outputs ALL print statements(base and HH functions) without error when run via the (Ubuntu) command prompt.

**Overview of code:**

**PHP creates R syntax and writes to file Rsyntax.txt.  Some of the following lines are located in the R syntax  file:**

```
dir = '/var/www/someDirectory/';
setwd(dir);
sink('record.lis', append=FALSE, split=TRUE);

print('hello-1');
test <- hov.bf(Values,Grouping);
print('hello-2');

q();
```

After syntax file is generated, PHP then runs:

```
exec("/usr/bin/Rscript /var/www/someDirectory/Rsyntax.txt --no-save", $output);
```

When run through PHP, the output file will contain all output created *above* the call to hov.bf(), but nothing seems to run after this call.  That is, "hello-1" is present in the output file, but "hello-2" and all other output below the hov.bf() call is not written to the file.  However, when I copy and paste the exact command from PHP's exec() to Ubuntu's command prompt, it runs *all* R syntax without issue.  I have also tried setting the .Rprofile to load the HH package as a default when R is loaded, but this did not resolve the issue through PHP.

If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate them.  I've run out of ideas for what it might be.

Thank you.

Comment: I would add a `sink()` line to close the file.

Comment: Tried adding sink() to end of Rsyntax.txt.  No change in output. R still seems to stop at the hov.bf function.

Comment: The other issue is that there would not normally be values for HH::hov.bf, Values, or Grouping at startup. I do not see that your used require() or any setting of the . I would have imagined there to have been an error thrown at that point in the code. You have split the outputs. What does the error log say?

Comment: Apologies, these are defined earlier in the syntax file.  I can confirm that these are being populated with the correct values. I can add specific code if you'd prefer, but there will be a number of statements to get to the actual values used in this function... Dumb question; where is the split output (in addition to record.lis) stored at? No prompt is open upon executing this.

Comment: I don't know what stderr() will return (normally set to the "terminal" in a console session), but why not put a `print(stderr())` call instead of the first print call?

Comment: print(stderr()) output is below.  No change in behavior regarding output once hov.bf is reached. description       class        mode        text      opened    can read 
   "stderr"  "terminal"         "w"      "text"    "opened"        "no" 
  can write 
      "yes"

Comment: Looks like some sort of error may be getting send to the "terminal" and perhaps it is not finding the right connection to write to. Take a look here: `http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=888`

Comment: Update:  I ran the following code x<-require('HH'); x; and it returns FALSE.  Therefore, it appears that the HH package is not loading properly when I execute R through PHP.  Anyone have any ideas as to why the library is not loading properly when using Rscript and an external R syntax file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered the issue.

Using the `.libPaths()` function, I was able to determine that the default directory that the HH package installed into was **not** included in the library paths when running Rscript through PHP, even though it was appearing when R was executing the same code through the command prompt.

I've resolved the issue by include a separate call to `.libPaths('new/file/path');` in my dynamically created syntax.  When I do this,

```
test <-require('HH'); 
test; 
returns TRUE;
```

Thanks to all who helped.

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it